# Does the state I get my license in affect my taxes, or how I file?

Tags: income-tax, taxes, california

I'm visiting my old house in California and only drive when in CA.  I am about to get my license renewed, but I work in NYC and spend most of my time there (95%).  I never drive when in NYC.

Will me getting my license in California affect my taxes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, but whether or not you drive in New York, the New York State Department of Motor Vehicles requires you to get a license in New York and surrender your California license. [According to their website](http://www.nydmv.state.ny.us/license.htm):

> If you become a
>   [resident](http://www.nydmv.state.ny.us/resident.htm)
>   of NYS, you must get a NYS driver
>   license within 30 days and surrender
>   your out-of-state driver license.
>   Normally, you cannot have a NYS driver
>   license and a driver license from
>   another state, but there are
>   exceptions. It is a violation of
>   Federal law to hold more than one
>   commercial driver license (CDL).

Comment: Ah yes, a very good point.

Comment: Does that mean it is illegal to reside in NYS without having a drivers license at all?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a question of where you have your driver's license.  It is a question of the states' tax related residency rules.  (Though a driver's license can be a part of that question.)

Since you likely have a residence in NYC and so can prove residency through a lease, bills, etc., you probably have to file as a NYS/NYC resident.

I do have to question your maintaining a California driver's license if you are not a resident.  If you are attempting to maintain dual-residency, look into both states' residency rules to see if you are liable for taxes in both states.

California seems particularly picky about these types of situations, probably due to concerns that you may be trying to circumvent California taxes.  That said, it usually revolves around income in the state.  Of course, if you maintain residency in California as well, the argument can be made that you owe some taxes due to the fact that you take advantage of state services.  (E.g. you drive on California roads.)

I suggest you consult a tax professional knowledgeable in these issues to sort out the details.

Comment: For the record; I'm legitimately in NYC most of the time... I'm being honest and not trying to circumvent anything.  I'll pay whatever is fair

Comment: @maker I was not trying to suggest that you were.  However, that is the taxman's primary concern.  I do not believe there is anything wrong with maintaining dual-residency.  Nor do I believe that there is anything wrong with legitimately minimizing your tax liability.  However, dual-residency likely complicates things.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from.  Now that Google has all my information; should the Government need to audit my 'freedom' of speech then I felt compelled to say that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Driver's license isn't relevant. If NYS considers you a part-year resident, they assess income tax on a *pro rata* basis. NY is broke now, so expect them to be really obnoxious about it if you make a lot of money. California probably has a similar policy.

If you really make a lot of money, the demands of the states in these matters are insane. I've read of cases where a state has actually demanded that an individual provide documentation of their in-/out-of-state status for every day of the year!